# How can I download an image from my local directory?

Tags: python-3.x, file

Definitely, I'm going to do **my PC crawling.** 
I want to get an image from an HTML document on my PC. 
I tried **this:**

```
n=0
for i in soup.find_all('div', class_='c_img'):
    with open('FILE DIRECTORY', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        r=f.read()
    with open(str(n)+'.jpg', 'wb', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(r)
    n+=1
```

And I got:
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xea in position 5: invalid continuation byte`
So I tried `encoding='utf-16'`
But it threw `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 44-45: illegal encoding`
How can I make it? Thanks.

Comment: Are you encoding a `.jpg` with `utf-8`?

Comment: What is 'FILE DIRECTORY'? Is it the jpg file?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue arises because you're attempting to encode a `.jpg` with `utf-8`.

You've posted only a small portion of your code, and I'm not sure what the other code does, but you should open the `.jpg` file as `'wb'` without specifying an encoding.

If your `"FILE DIRECTORY"` file contains the `.jpg`, open it with `'rb'` again, with no encoding.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know what 'rb' or 'wb' means.